# I want to run a new project in django and I get this error :ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf'

Tags: python, django, cmd, virtualenv, new-project

I created a project in virtualenv on windows and then tried to run it and this error occurred:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 67, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\django_project\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\django_project\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 225, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 219, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 153, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Windows\System32\django\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf'
```

here's my apps versions

---

```
- asgiref    3.2.7
- Django     3.0.5
- pip        20.0.2
- pytz       2019.3
- setuptools 41.2.0
- sqlparse   0.3.1
```

1. My files :

   - manage.py
   - django_project :

     - asgi.py
     - settings.py
     - urls.py
     - wsgi.py
     - **init**.py

I try building virtualenv in the project and still not working .

please help me :)

Comment: Python 3.9 is an alpha release. I recommend you install the latest 3.8.x release (currently 3.8.2), create a new virtual env and install Django in that. If you're still stuck, please show the commands you used to create the virtual env, install Django and start runserver.

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to activate your virtualenv

   source ~/your_virtual_env_directory/Scripts/activate

   2. run command in your project directory

   python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

## Use pipenv for making virtual environment

steps:

1.) locate your project using terminal lets say cd/desktop/myproject

2.) then use the following command (you can change the django version if you like)

```
pipenv install django==3.0.1
```

then start the virtual enviroment using

```
pipenv shell
```

it will create your virtual enviorment something like this (myproject)$

3.) to quit virtual enviroment use

```
exit
```

4.) to start same virtual enviroment again use

```
pipenv shell
```